# Rfc2898DeriveBytes in java for this .Net code password encryption

Tags: java, c#, .net

I am trying to encrypt password in java which is connecting to the C# system below is the code. This encryption is done using Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

```
class StringCipher
{
    private const int Keysize = 256;
    private const int DerivationIterations = 1000;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {

        var saltStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var ivStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
        {
            var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);
            using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            var cipherTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
                            cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                            cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                            memoryStream.Close();
                            cryptoStream.Close();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy()
    {
        var randomBytes = new byte[32]; 
        using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        }
        return randomBytes;
    }
}
```

[.net Source code here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/474/getting-started-with-steganography-hide-information-on-images-with-c-sharp)

below is what I have tried  in java and it is not working for me,.net encryption is done using Rfc2898DeriveBytes, and here i have used             SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(); as an equivalent for that, but for some reason I am not able to get the password encrypted. please help

```
public class PasswordEncryption {
    private final static int DerivationIterations = 1000;
     private final int Keysize = 256;

    private static byte[] getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    public static String Encrypt(String plainText, String passPhrase)
             {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        byte[] saltStringBytes = getSalt();
        byte[] IvStringBytes=getSalt();
        byte[] pwd = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        char[] chars = passPhrase.toCharArray();
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        System.out.println(secretKey.toString());
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding","BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(pwd);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(saltStringBytes);
        outputStream.write(IvStringBytes);
        outputStream.write(result);

        byte end[] = outputStream.toByteArray();

        String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(end);
        System.out.println(base64Encoded);

        return base64Encoded;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Encrypt("passwordhere", "ABC");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not encrypt passwords, just use Rfc2898DeriveBytes to create a password verifier. The password should not be recoverable, that is a security vulnerability. When the attacker gains admin rights and obtains the encrypted password he will also get the encryption key and thus obtain the passwords along with the rest of the user credentials.

Create the password verifier by using Rfc2898DeriveBytes and save the salt and rounds count along with the derived password.

When verifying a password run the supplied password through Rfc2898DeriveBytes with the saved salt and rounds count and then compare the result with the saved derivation.

Comment: .net system cannot be edited, we have access to java to create the similar encryption method. Please advise.

Comment: The question you have to ask is "How important to you is your user's security?" If the answer is "very important" then do not encrypt passwords and use current best practices. OTOH if you answer is "don't give a damn" go ahead and encrypt the passwords. It is a simple decision.